# imputing missing data with softImpute in R

Tags: r, missing-data, categorical-data

I'm trying to impute missing values but I have problem dealing with categorical variables. The command `softImpute` calculate the missing values but they also turn categorical variables, which is inadequate for the analysis. For the missing values I did the following

```
>softImp = softImpute(as.matrix(train), rank.max = 60)
>data.comp = softImp$u %*% diag(softImp$d) %*% t(softImp$v)
>data.comp=data.frame(data.comp)
```

However when I look at categorical variables they are in decimal points

```
> head(data.comp$X91)
[1] 0.6037109 0.6263665 0.5373208 0.6092270 0.8796817 0.8643236
```

which is originally

```
> head(train[c(91)])
  H0001600
1        0
2        0
3        1
4        1
5        0
6        1
```

Is there a certain way to impute missing values for categorical variables? I Any other suggestions dealing with missing values in categorical variables would also help a lot.

Comment: Have you considered choosing a threshold that would classify your  values as 0 or 1?

Comment: I don't know about thresholds - I don't think I can choose one since the data only provides the categorical variable.

Comment: By "classifying values as 0 or 1" do you mean recoding them as dummy variables?

Comment: For example, if a value is < 0.5, then it is classified as 0, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to decide the threshold, since there is no actual data which the categorical values are based on.